# Effective screen designing with attractive UI font style attributes

Tags: android, user-interface, screen

I have opted a font style as bold|italic and when I check it into my emulator is working very fine! I could be able to type on edittext box in Italic font style but when it comes to Android Mobile (Samsung Galaxy), all the edit and text fields are displaying by using Bold font style than Italic font. I have attached here my screen part (Emulator part).

What mistake I have done here?

[image: Screenshot]

This is my code,

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView_Name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/name"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textStyle="bold|italic"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText_Name"
style="@style/spinner_style1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="Type Name here"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textStyle="bold|italic" 
android:text="" />
```

Comment: For your second question, the UI Stack Exchange site may be a good source. Bear in mind that no Stack Exchange site is supposed have questions related to product recommendations, so you may wish to rephrase.

Comment: @zyboxinternational - Oh okay, I am sorry. Will do rephrase,thanks for your kind information!

Comment: I believe I have found the solution and I have changed my answer.  Let me know if it works for you